# Restful Get Json from URL by POST method and add to DB?

Tags: php, zend-framework, rest, post

I have a postAction in my Controller. Then I send JSON by curl with POST method

```
{
    "first_name":"Nguyen",
    "last_name":"Tien Hai",
    "dob":"1991-07-09",
    "sex":"F",
    "address":"80\/280 Tran Nguyen Han",
    "email":"ngannk01530@fpt.edu.vn",
    "phone":"0164-960-8628",
    "avatar_link":"avatar",
    "last_login":"00:00:00"
}
```

I don't know how to get this json and convert to array, i tried:

```
$request = $this->getRequest(); 
$rawBody = $request->getRawBody();
```

But it isn't working. And I don't know how to insert the data to Database too.

Comment: ý bạn là dùng ajax ý hả?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
json_decode($request->getBody(), true);
```